# Cannot find symbol for ActivityMainBindingImpl ^

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

If I remove app:userList="@{viewModel.userList}" from RecyclerView inside activity_main.xml, it is able to build project, but using it gives me error: cannot find symbol for ActivityMainBindingImpl                                                         ^

Following are the files:

1. activity_main.xml

   ```
    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.databindingmvvmrespositoryjava.data.viewmodel.UserViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User List"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:userList="@{viewModel.userList}"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
   ```

   ```
    </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. MainActivity.java

   ```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        UserViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter();
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Observe changes in user list
        viewModel.getUserList().observe(this, users -> adapter.setUserList(users));
    }
   ```

   }
3. list_item

   ```
    <data>

        <variable
            name="userData"
            type="com.example.databindingmvvmrespositoryjava.data.model.User" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{userData.name}"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. UserAdapter

   ```
    public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<User> userList;

    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ListItemBinding binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = userList.get(position);
        holder.binding.setUserData(user);
        holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ListItemBinding binding;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull ListItemBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }
   ```

   }
5. UserViewModel

   ```
    public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<List<User>> userList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserViewModel() {
        userRepository = new UserRepository();
        fetchUsers();
    }

    public LiveData<List<User>> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    private void fetchUsers() {
        userRepository.getUsers(new UserRepository.UserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<User> users) {

                for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); ++i) {
                    Log.i("onresponse....", "onSuccess: " + users.get(i).getName());
                }

                userList.setValue(users);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String errorMessage) {
                // Handle failure
            }
        });
    }
   ```

   }
6. User.java

   ```
    public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: And where's your BindingAdapter for that custom property userList in RecyclerView?